# On which site to ask for a self-hosted web app?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, site-recommendation

I am looking for a document management web application (Self-hosted, preferably based on PHP) with specific requirements. I would like to ask this as a question to make sure I don't overlook a big name in the market.

What is the most valid site to ask this on? Webapps is out because it's not for self-hosted apps. Webmasters doesn't really fit either. Is SO still the best place for this?

Comment: Wouldn't this be O/T as [Shopping Advice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) on most SE sites?

Answer (score 2):

Try SF - Document Management Servers are squarely in the realm of Sysadmins.

Comment: I would like to ask a very similar question, but SF and Programmers have countless questions closed on this topic. Is there no SE for specifically requesting SaaS, library or API suggestions? Example: http://serverfault.com/questions/105195/recommendation-for-document-management-solution?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `SO`, but my first thought was `Programmers`.

Comment: Programmers? For an application recommendation? Naaah. Not really?

Comment: Well, here is an example of a question moved from SO to programmers that is more of an app recommendation: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29720/web-framework-for-education-management-system

Comment: wow, that is surprising. Wouldn't have thought that. Thanks

Comment: @Pekka, yes to me the line between SO and programmers can be really fuzzy on some topics.